# HI All is there any way to update API version for apex classes in bulk

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code

[Is there a way to upgrade api versions of all apex classes without manually updating each of them?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229795/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-api-versions-of-all-apex-classes-without-manually-upda)

I have read this link and try to achieve but not able to deploy in the sandbox using the VS code.

Is there any other ways to update the API version for all apex classes and triggers?

Comment: Can you elaborate "Unable to deploy"? Are there any issues?

Comment: I have a requirement to upgrade API version to all apex classes and apex triggers and I have find and replaced all versions from a mata.XML file and try to deploy a group of metadata like classes and got successful deployment message but when I check in the sandbox apex classes API version not updated. So, can you tell me how can I upgrade api versions.

Comment: You can just use metadata api of sfdx to retrieve all classes, then change api version in meta xml files and deploy them back

Comment: The linked question includes multiple correct solutions. Please [edit] your post to elaborate on how you achieved this; it is likely a procedural mistake.

Comment: If you have complication with vs code you can also do it from workbench - first retrieve all apex classes, extract the zip, modify the api version in each, create new zip file and deploy it with workbench. + Probably you can use some editor like notepad++ to modify all meta.xml files from the zip in bulk

Comment: You can also deploy using the sfdx CLI.